# Building RaLink RT2860 WiFi Network driver (kernel 3.0.4 x64)

Tags: build, kernel, wifi, driver

I have a problem to build the rt2860 wifi driver.
Its the first time i have to do this.
I downloaded the driver from the RaLink website, modified it and then i ran make as root.

```
root:2010_07_16_RT2860_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0/ $ make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/root/2010_07_16_RT2860_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/root/2010_07_16_RT2860_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0/tools'
/home/root/2010_07_16_RT2860_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/root/2010_07_16_RT2860_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.0.4/build SUBDIRS=/home/root/2010_07_16_RT2860_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.0.4/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.0.4/build'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

This error message makes me assume, that there should be a makefile with a target named 'modules'. The build folder is absolutely empty... what to do now? Should i get the specific kernel sources and place them into /lib/modules/3.x.x/build/?

EDIT:

I also downloaded the firmware files and
my distri. is Crux.

```
root:~/ $ grep -i rt2800pci /boot/linux-3.0.4-x64
# CONFIG_RT2800PCI is not set

root:~/ $ for BUSID in $(lspci | awk '{ IGNORECASE=1 } /net/ { print $1 }');  do lspci -s $BUSID -m; lspci -s $BUSID -n; done
03:00.0 "Network controller" "RaLink" "RT2860" "Unknown vendor 1a3b" "Device 1059"
03:00.0 0280: 1814:0781
```

Answer (score 1):

There rt2xx-based devices are already supported in the mainline kernel quite well, so there's no need to download anything from the RaLink website. The kernel module for the RT2860 is "rt2800pci".

You can either run menuconfig, select this driver as a module and rebuild OR you can use the [compat-wireless package](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download).

EDIT: You will also need the firmware for it (rt2860.bin). You can get it from [the firmware-ralink Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/de/sid/firmware-ralink).

Comment: `root:/ $ find / -name 'rt*.ko'
/lib/modules/3.0.4/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
/lib/modules/3.0.4/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2500pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.0.4/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
/lib/modules/3.0.4/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2400pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.0.4/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.0.4/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt61pci.ko
root:/ $ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.`

Comment: It seems that the driver was not selected at all at config time OR it it built-in. Please run `grep -i rt2800pci /boot/config-\`uname -r\``. If you get `CONFIG_RT2800PCI=n`, the you need to reconfigure your kernel. Also check out my edit about the firmware.

Comment: thank you for your effort. this config value is not set... see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm using debian-sid on a eeepc1000 that has a ralink as well.

when i was on the 2.6 kernels, i had to add all in-kernel drivers for ralink to the blacklist, and compile that.

when i upgraded to kernel 3.2 it was a mess. i had some new module in the kernel that was not affected by the blacklist somewhat working with the card... my AP got only 10% signal or so, and it was messy...

after upgrading the debian package (from linux-image-3.2.0-3 to 3.2.0-4) the support was completely gone.

i got it back by removing the blacklist. the modules i'm using now are rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci

so, if you compiled the drivers on 2.6 and added the blacklists... simply remove the blacklists and ignore whatever you had compiled (the STA drivers... they will not even be probed if the ones in the kernel work for you. but if they are being probed, add the STA ones to the blacklist)

I honestely do not know hows the support on 3.0, but on 3.2 it's as good as it was on 2.6 with the ra drivers.